# Is using the "escape" tag really mandatory as a good security pattern in Django?

Tags: django, security, templates, escaping

In [the security chapter](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter19/) of [The Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/), it says that I must always use the template tag `{% escape %}` in order to protect my site from cross-site scripting.

Is it really necessary to put the escape tag on every single template string? Is there a way to specify this at application level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That version of the Django book was written well before 1.0 came out, and is significantly out of date. All template content has been autoescaped for quite some time now.

Comment: Phew, I'm glad they did that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In django is been done automatically. To turn it off you have to use the autoescape tag. I'm not sure since when, but at least since 1.1 version.

```
{% autoescape off %}
  safe stuff
{% endautoscape %}
```